# How to use the word "piquant"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I referred the meaning for the word piquant and the [dictionary online](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/piquant) gives two contexts in which it can be used

1) taste : piquant taste

2) attractive and charming : piquant face

But I am seeing the usage of the word in the context like "piquant situation" ...

for example

> MYSORE: Fire brand leader and champion of backward classes in Karnataka, Siddaramaiah seems to have been caught in a *piquant* situation with his hasty decision to resign from the opposition leader's post. [Times of India](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/mysore/Siddaramaiah-in-a-piquant-situation/articleshow/13971253.cms)

and

> CPM Leadership in *Piquant* Situation [New Indian Express](http://www.newindianexpress.com/states/kerala/CPM-Leadership-in-Piquant-Situation/2014/01/29/article2025691.ece)

From the context I am interpreting it as an uncomfortable and tough situation .
why is the usage not listed in the dictionary . Is this right way of using it ?

Comment: I would guess that the usage is not in the dictionary because it is peculiar to Indian English.

Comment: May  I know the reason for the negative vote ?

Comment: Try another dictionary: http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/piquant. When I need to look up dictionary definitions, I always go to http://onelook.com/. There I can see what several dictionaries have to say

Comment: so is the so called 'indian usage' right or wrong ? Is there something so peculiar like Indian english ? I ve heard of American and british english

Comment: Indian English(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_English) is one of the many varieties of English. There is nothing 'wrong' about Indian English, but some of its feature sound strange to a speaker of, for example, British English.

Comment: Harish, there is no governing body of English who can determine in all times and places what is right and wrong. That dictionaries don't record this sense or gloss of *piquant* indicates the usage is unusual, which is probably the closest you're going to get to a determination.  With that said, while there is a large body of English speakers in India, which may some day come to rival the populations in countries like the UK and USA, the difference between those speakers and Indian speakers is Indians are almost always using English as a *second* language.

Comment: @Harish: *"peculiar to"* is [an idiom](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/74490/peculiar-vs-peculiar-to-itself) that means *"only occurs in"* (but maybe it's not an idiom in Indian English); it doesn't mean something is weird. And I think Indian English has to be considered a valid dialect of English. Certainly, you're not going to convince Indians to stop using *"prepone"* because it's not a word in American or British English.

Comment: Thanks all . @PeterShor oh its a good information that "prepone" is an Indian english word . Ya I searched for it now and it does not show up in merriam (http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/prepone) . Ok what is the equivalent word in American and british english ?

Comment: @Harish: the closest equivalent to *"prepone"* in AmE and BrE is *"move forward"*. There's no equivalent word.

Answer (score 3):

Searching for Indian English piquant shows multiple references to food, and definitions of piquant tend to indicate pungent or indeed spicy food. For food, this is agreeable, but in this case, it's indicative of a *hot* situation. In American English, a person who is in a piquant situation is in "hot water".

Answer (score 0):

The word derives from the verb ***to pique***, which [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pique) defines as

> to excite (interest, curiosity, etc.)

Something that *piques* one interest, curiosity or taste buds for that matter, can be described as being ***piquant***.

In your quoted usage Siddaramaiah is described as being in a *piquant* situation.  IF the author's intent was to mean that his situation was exciting or stimulating in some way, then the author could be correct. However I beleive that their intent was more toward "touchy, tricky, tenuous" in which case *piquant* is probably no the right word to use.

EDIT:
IF one looks further, the verb derives from the French *piquer* which means to prick (as with a pin or sword point) and therefore one could reasonably argue that *piquant* might also mean *prickly* which could fit here. But that isn't the typcial usage in AmE or BrE as far as I know.